# Motive to motive via Langlands

Tags: nt.number-theory, langlands-conjectures

I have been tying myself in knots trying to straighten out this speculative circle of connections, no doubt because I am just a novice in these matters, so I thought I'd pop the question here and learn if it might not be arrant nonsense:

Take $E$, a pure motive over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $G_M(E)$ be its motivic Galois group.

$G_M(E)$ is a reductive group. Assume it is connected.

Conjecturally to each $L$-algebraic automorphic representation of $G_M(E)$ is attached a $p$-adic Galois representation, $\varphi$, into the $L$-group of $G_M(E)$.

Suppose $\varphi$ is geometric. Then, $\varphi$ is a realization of a motive $E_\varphi$.

How are the motives $E$ and $E_\varphi$ related - directly, geometrically? Or indeed, how is the entire collection of $E_\varphi$'s, one for each geometric Galois representation attached to an algebraic automorphic representation of the motivic Galois group of $E$, related to $E$?

Comment: Are you sure this is right? I think the correct data for $\phi$ is a representation of $G_M(E)$ in the sense of algebraic groups, not an automorphic rep -- so e.g. $G_M(E)$ could be something like $GL_2$ and $\phi$ could be something like $Sym^2$.